# How do I make a dependency diagram with HTML/CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

This is a common type of dependency diagram we use in Latex, I was wondering how I can make this for a webpage.

[image]

Comment: Definitely not with flexbox.

Comment: there are so many libraries that you can use to build like this diagram, you have to google it depends on the framework you're using